# Java 8 stream, obtain average age by country

Tags: java-8, java-stream

I'm trying to get into functional programming on java 8

**User class**

```
public class User {
    private String name;
    private Country country;
    private int age;
    // setters - getters
}
```

**Country class**

```
public class Country {
    private String name;
    private int population;
    //setters - getters
}
```

Now I want to get the average age of Users by Country, basically a `Map<String, Double>`. I can do it the old way just by iterating the users list. However I would like to implement it in a `functional` way , with `stream`. I know about `collect` and `groupingBy`.

I tried  `users.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(user -> user.getCountry()));` and get a `Map<String, List<User>>`. Can't figure out how to do the averaging part.

Comment: have a look here https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingBy-java.util.function.Function-java.util.stream.Collector-

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Add a second parameter to `groupingBy`

```
Map<String, Double> map = users
    .stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
           user -> user.getCountry().getName(),
           Collectors.averagingInt(User::getAge)));
```